# CSS not rendering because of multi-classes

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser, compatibility

I have a problem with my CSS. Everything is working fine in modern browsers like FF, chrome, IE9 and IE8. Now the problem is happening on IE6 (of course) and IE7.

I would say 80% of my css is ignored in those two browsers.  For information im using a HTML5 doctype.

For exemple:

```
<div id="bgVideoContainer">
    <div class="borderTop"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div class="boxes fleft">
```

And css:

```
.borderTop {
       position: relative;
       top: 0;
       border-top: 1px solid black;
 }

.boxes {
        margin: 0 0 15px;
        padding: 0 25px;
        width: 924px;
 }

.fleft { float:left; }
```

And a lot of this  structure:

```
<div id="videoCanvas">
    <div class="column-left">
        <object id="videoContainer"

#videoCanvas .column-left #videoContainer {
        width:600px;
        height:473px;
        background-color:#000;
        color:#fff;
 }
```

And none of this is showing on IE7 and 6 .... Im confused, what should I do to fix that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

You can create a separate style sheets for `IE6 and 7`. And use the necessary .`css` classes to those style sheets.

Use developer tool in `IE` browser (ctrl + F12) and edit the classes accordingly

eg.

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link href="IE-7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

IE6 to IE8 doesn't recognize html5 elements. For more information click [here](http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?cid=8C170)!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the DOCTYPE to check that's not the problem?

Also, any chance of linking to the work?

Is there a place in your CSS after which IE doesn't work? Could be a broken style somewhere if it isn't the DOCTYPE.